# Javascript alert,vfpage and apex

Tags: javascript

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I have created vfpage,  datatable consits of some records ,save and 1 actionfunction method.
My req is i have **checkbox** and **materialno** as columns.
if  checkbox is selected and materialno '25' selected alert should display like "please select 26" and record should not save.once we 26 material is selected the record should save without any alerts.
anyone condition is satisfied alert should come,not for both.

I have used client side because server side id's are dynamically generating.

For me the requirement is working fine,alert also coming but the record should not save, it should stay on the samepage.only when the condition satisfies it should save.

OK I am posting pseudo code
******vfpage***********

```
   <apex:pageBlock title="Movie Table" id="pageblock" >
      <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" id="cb"  value="Save" onclick="test();"/>
  </apex:pageBlock>
 <apex:pageBlock id="pb1">
  <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbs" title="1st group" collapsible="false">
    <apex:dataTable id="dt" value="{!mt}" var="mlist" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0"  width="100%">
    <apex:column id="c">
             <apex:facet name="header"><center>Select to ADD</center></apex:facet>        
             <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!mlist.select__c}" id="checkbox" > </apex:inputCheckbox>
             </apex:column>          
   <apex:column >
             <apex:facet name="header"><center>Material</center></apex:facet>        
             <apex:outputText value="{!mlist.name__c}" />
      </apex:column>

    </apex:dataTable>     
  </apex:pageBlockSection>   

  </apex:pageblock>
  <script>

      function test(){
        addmat();          
      }
      </script>

 <apex:outputPanel id="newmaterial">
<script>
if('{!mtext}'=='25'){
alert(' plese select 26);
}   
</script>
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:actionFunction name="addmat" action="{!material}" id="newac" rerender="newmaterial"></apex:actionFunction> 


  </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

***********apex class*******

```
public class Movietable{


public List<Movie__c> mt{get;set;}
public List<Movie__c> mt1{get;set;}
public boolean m25{get;set;}
public String mtext{get;set;}
public Movietable(ApexPages.standardController stdController) {

 mt=[select id, name__c,select__c,Cinemas__c from Movie__c];

 }

 public PageReference save() { 
 mt=[select id, name__c,select__c,Cinemas__c from Movie__c];
 PageReference pr;

   return null;


}
public PageReference material() { 
    Integer i=mt.size();
    for(Integer j=0;j<i;j++){
      if(mt[j].select__c==true && mt[j].name__c=='25'){
      m25=true;
      mtext='25';

   }
}
return null;


}

}
```

FRom controller only I need to handle for this issue because id's are dynamically generating in my original code so please help me out

Comment: For a more accurate and quicker answer to your problem you should paste your code in your question as well. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to post relevant code for us to help you.

Comment: I cannot post my code due to security reasons.

Comment: then you should simplify the code to its essence and use variable names like `foo`, and `bar`

Comment: @crop what ur comment means?i didn get

Comment: If your code can't be posted for security reasons, create a new sanitized version so community can help.

Comment: I have added the code please find above and guide me how to proceed further